# Corrupted grub, cannot boot nor use boot-repair

Tags: boot, grub2

My Ubuntu Linux 18.04 laptop played up yesterday. It would not boot.  When I tried a few times it came up with command line only and said "Alpine Linux"
I have never heard of this and certainly did not install it.
I tried removing it but corrupted GRUB.  So I created a USB thumb drive with boot repair.  I can easily boot onto this and run boot repair, but it fails every time when installing grub.  I get to the part where I paste the three lines into a terminal. This fails every time.
The error message says I am missing linux-generic files and terminates.  Then boot repair then says I have no grub on dev/sda  and that me finished.  If I reboot the BIOS says no operating system found.

I can mount /dev/sda1 and see all of my folders and files.  So at least I copied them onto a portable drive.  I cant think of a way forward apart from a full disk wipe and start again.

Any ideas?
Here is my pastebin
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/v2phbcRjhy/

thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Your `fstab`-file is broken, your boot-info-summary shows the content of `/etc/fstab` in line 465-470 as

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/cdrom  /media/cdrom    iso9660 noauto,ro 0 0
/dev/usbdisk    /media/usb  vfat    noauto,ro 0 0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This does not look like a correct `fstab`-file.
As you can mount the partition, you can rebuild this file. To get the correct device UUID's take a look at line 64 and 65:

```
/dev/sda1        afd8ae45-a329-445c-b4d5-5bb51031e197 ext4
/dev/sda5        ad5b64c5-4247-4331-853d-e162d49b4963   swap
```

Using this information, your `fstab`-file should look like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>                       <mount point> <type>   <options>          <dump>  <pass>
UUID=afd8ae45-a329-445c-b4d5-5bb51031e197    /       ext4    errors=remount-ro    0       1
UUID=ad5b64c5-4247-4331-853d-e162d49b4963    none    swap    sw                   0       0
```

So you need to mount the partition `sda1` and then edit the file `/path/to/mountpoint/etc/fstab`. You will need root privileges to do so. With corrected `fstab` your system should be fine to boot normally.

Another caeveat I see is in the lines 621,622 in your boot-info-summary. To get rid of the entry `recordfail=1` in `/boot/grub/grubenv` you could simply rename this file to `/boot/grub/grubenv.bak`, a fresh file can be recreated when the system is running with `sudo grub-editenv /boot/grub/grubenv create`. If this doesn't help, the original file can be renamed back to it's former name.

I think it doesn't make sense to run boot-repair again, boot-repair reports no errors when installing the boot-loader (lines 842,843). It looks like the culprit is something what boot-repair isn't able to repair.

I can't tell you, where `Alpine Linux` comes from, we can also find it in the boot-info-summary at line 20. Take a look at `/etc/issue`.

> I tried removing it but corrupted GRUB

It would be very helpful if you can tell us what you have done to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change but still dont have a boot operating system.  Do I now run boot repair again?

Comment: @SimonBunn Please see my edit.

Comment: I gave up and started again with a clean install.  Surprised that rebuilding the boot on Ubuntu is almost impossible whereas on Windows it is trivial and always works

Comment: Maybe that's the fastest way to solve the problem. I'm sure a repair would have been possible, but just to find out what's going on may take more time than a reinstall.